# What is strange square above input in start menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I have some strange gray square above strat mennu input.
How I use start menu:
I press `windows` key on my keyboard ant start typing software I want to run.

So, when I press Windows key, I see normal start menu.
When I type, I see big gray sqare above input box.
When I press `tab` button to move focus to another element (such as buttons in top menu), this gray square disappears. If I continue pressing `tab` to return focus to input, gray square appears again.

I think it is part of input box for something like suggestions.
What is is and how can I remove it?

[image: Screenshot attached]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Areas where web content would load remotely (from Bing, Microsoft) to show web queries related to your input.